# Can't return localized AM/PM format of time using Carbon formatLocalized method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, php-carbon

I want to return Arabic localized time to be like this

- **9:00 ص**

so i set carbon locale in boot method of AppServiceProvider class

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}
```

and then use carbon to parse the fetched time from database and use formatLocalized method with format to show hours and minutes 
like this

```
$time = Carbon::parse('09:00:00')->formatLocalized('%I:%M %p');
```

but it return time like this

- **9:00 PM**

Is there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After deep searching using of isoFormat method achieve what I want

```
$time = Carbon::parse('09:00:00')->isoFormat('h:mm a');
```

then the output will be

- ** 9:00 ص**

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it on a per call basis, if you need to:

```
$dateTimeLocal->locale(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale())->isoFormat('h:mma')
```

Note that the letters used to output a date time are different than with `format()`. For example, `g:ia` and `h:mma` produce the same output from `format()` and `isoFormat()` respectively.